# loop through sheets and cells to find value and runtime error 13 Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

What I would like to achieve is to write some code that will loop through all the sheets and rows of those sheets until it finds value of the combobox(cmbPrdcde.value) and for test purposes only, when found, color that cell Red.
I found the code below on a Microsoft website. The code loops through all the worksheets.

```
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim i As Integer

WS_Count = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook).Worksheets.Count

    For i = 1 To WS_Count
        Code Here
    Next i
```

I would like to incorporate the code below with it so it would look like the code below:

```
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim i As Integer

If cmbPrdCde.Value <> " " Then

WS_Count = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook).Worksheets.Count

    For i = 4 To WS_count
        If Cells(x, 2) = cmbPrdCde.Value Then
           Cells(x, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next i

End If
```

Sheet 4 starts where the information is held.
However when I run the code I get a Run-time error'13' Type mismatch 
and WS_count = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook).Worksheets.Count is highlighted in yellow.

Comment: Why not just use the `.Find` function?

Comment: I'm sorry. I am still new to VBA and haven't learned all the, I'm assuming a method. Could you post an example and will it do the same thing as what I am wanting? Remember the information starts on page 4 and continues on different sheets.Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: No, its a combobox

Comment: Is there some limit to the range that needs to be searched? Is it just Column B you need to look in?

Comment: Your error line should be `ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count`. However, you are just going to get an error on the next line. You are also not utilizing your `i` loop and you try to enter an `x` loop without any instruction. Right now, `x = 0` which will result in a invalid range / error.

Comment: Were you by chance looking at [this Microsoft website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/142126/macro-to-loop-through-all-worksheets-in-a-workbook)? Note that the original is actually `WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count`, which would not throw a Type Mismatch error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, & `Sheet3` to the names of the sheets that you do not want this code to run on.

It looks like you were trying to loop through `Column B` so the below code will check for your `ComboBox` value on all sheets - *with exception of 3 above* -from `B2` until last used cell in the column.

Also, it looks like you were testing for your `ComboBox.Value <> " "` which is testing if the value is not equal to a space. Assuming you are looking for blanks, it should be '""', which is what I updated the code to be.

---

```
Sub Find_Me()

Dim ws As Worksheet, i

If cmbPrdCde.Value <> "" Then
    For Each ws In Worksheets  'Loop through Sheets
        If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" And ws.Name <> "Sheet2" And ws.Name <> "Sheet3" Then
            For i = 2 To ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row   'Loop through Rows
                If ws.Range("B" & i) = cmbPrdCde.Value Then
                    ws.Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = vbRed
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next ws
End If

End Sub
```

---

You can boost run-time by toggling off screen updating before loop and re-enabling before ending the sub with:

`Application.ScreenUpdating = False` then `True` respectively

Comment: But what if more sheets are added. Is there not away to program it to do this for me? i.e. For Each sheet in workbook(ChattemPackaging.xlsm) Find this.... Thank You.